Why environment variable value is changed implicitly from N to false during kubernetes deployment?
I introduced a environment variable called mongo_switch: N(Not mongo_switch: "N",no double quote around N ) in local application.yml in springboot 3.1.5.  In program, I use the variable like below and expect logic reach path #1. It is working perfectly in local.
if(mongo_switch.equalsignorecase("N")){
 do something Path #1
} else {
 do other thing Path #2
}

But, after deployment to kubernetes, I surprisingly found logic entered Path #2 because the mongo_switch 's value implicitly became "false" (as String). So I adjust my code below as fix then problem solved.
if(mongo_switch.equalsignorecase("N") || mongo_switch.equalsingorecase("false")){
 do something Path #1
} else {
 do other thing Path #2
}

Despiste problem was solved, I still wonder : why that environment variable (mongo_switch) behave differently ? meaning, why its value varies between local and kubernetes ? Any reply would be much appreciated.

Your question comprises statements about facts without the facts. If you'd like us to help you explain, please show exactly what you did to set the environment variable locally and when deployed to Kubernetes so that we may help.

It would help to [edit] the question to include (a minimal excerpt of) your actual Kubernetes YAML file, the Spring properties file, and similar details.  In your code, what kind of thing is mongo_switch; how are you accessing it?
